# How to change textblock background?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

This is my `xaml structure`

```
<stackpanel>
  <textblock Text="A"></textblock>
  <textblock Text="B"></textblock>
</stackpanel>
```

`Stackpanel`, It can loop to generate more same structures.

How can I change background color of texblock when I click it?

**UPDATE**: `I just want change on xaml file not using C#.`

Default I has yellow, but when I click a textblock, Its background will change to Blue.

**UPDATE 2**: If click A, A will change to blue until I click another.

Detail:

1. I click A`(A is yellow)`, A will change to be blue ==> A is blue
2. I click B`(B is yellow and A is blue)`, B will change to be blue and A will change to be yellow.

**UPDATE 3**: How about this?

```
<stackpanel>
      <textblock Text="A"></textblock>
</stackpanel>

<stackpanel>
      <textblock Text="A"></textblock>
</stackpanel>
<stackpanel>
      <textblock Text="A"></textblock>
</stackpanel>
```

**The question is same above**

Thanks!

Comment: you'll need a custom control for that. the logic you need can not be dealt within the control itself but depends on other controls, thus a pure xaml solution is impossible

Comment: @ Andreas Müller How about **UPDATE 3**?

Comment: what about it? my answer should still work for that case too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using **EventTrigger** and **Color Animation** you can change color of TextBlock Background color on **MouseDown** or **MouseLeave**

---

**xaml code**

```
 <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" From="Yellow" To="Blue" Duration="0:0:0.1"></ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" From="Blue" To="Yellow" Duration="0:0:0.1"></ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="A" Background="Yellow"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="B" Background="Yellow"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

---

**Update**

Use **TextBox with property IsReadOnly=True** instead of textblock.

```
    <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox"> 
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter> 
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.GotFocus">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" From="Yellow" To="Blue" Duration="0:0:0.1"></ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.LostFocus">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" From="Blue" To="Yellow" Duration="0:0:0.1"></ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox Text="A"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="A"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks @Heena Patil, But when `MouseLeave` raise the color disappear. I want: When I click A (Yellow), A has changed to be blue and It will be blue until I click on B. Then B (yellow) will changed to be blue.

Comment: If I remove `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave"> ...  </EventTrigger>`, TextBlock's background always has blue after click it.

Answer (score 4):

Programmatically:

```
textBlock1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
```

In XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlock1">
    <TextBlock.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow" />
    </TextBlock.Background>
</TextBlock>
```

To change background color when you click on a textBlock, you should use custom style with triggers. This is not hard, if you will search or ask about using styles and triggers. You definetely should not use C# for this in XAML design patterns.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitrij A. I am searching another source.

Comment: my VS broken so i can't post triggers sample now.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <TextBlock Text="Hello, styled world!" FontSize="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                                <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

This willbe the solution for your problem most likely. As i pointed out a xaml only solution won't be possible due to the nature of your requirement that you want one control to be dependent on a varierty of other controls.

You can fiddle around with the rest of it of course.

```
public class RadioTextblock : TextBlock
{
    static RadioTextblock()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(RadioTextblock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(RadioTextblock)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Group", typeof (string), typeof (RadioTextblock), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string Group
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(GroupProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GroupProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ActiveColor", typeof (Brush), typeof (RadioTextblock), new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush)));

    public Brush ActiveColor
    {
        get { return (Brush) GetValue(ActiveColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActiveColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RestorationColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "RestorationColor", typeof (Brush), typeof (RadioTextblock), new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush)));

    public Brush RestorationColor
    {
        get { return (Brush) GetValue(RestorationColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RestorationColorProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);
        // there may be a better hook for this. but i'm not writing custom controls that often. anything after styles are applied should be good
        RestorationColor = Background;
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        RestoreOtherBackgrounds(this);
        base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
    }

    private void RestoreOtherBackgrounds(RadioTextblock radioTextblock)
    {
        var topParent = GetTopMostParent(radioTextblock);
        var controlsWithGroup = GetChildrenRecursive<RadioTextblock>(topParent).ToLookup(d => (string)d.GetValue(GroupProperty));
        var similar = controlsWithGroup[radioTextblock.Group];
        foreach (var match in similar)
        {
            if (match == radioTextblock)
            {
                match.Background = ActiveColor;
            }
            else
            {
                match.Background = match.RestorationColor;
            }
        }
    }

    private DependencyObject GetTopMostParent(RadioTextblock radioTextblock)
    {
        DependencyObject current = radioTextblock;
        while (current != null)
        {
            var cParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
            if (cParent == null || cParent == current)
                break;

            current = cParent;
        }

        return current;
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> GetChildrenRecursive<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        T casted;
        var childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current);
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            var currentChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
            casted = currentChild as T;
            if(casted != null)
                yield return casted;

            foreach (var subChild in GetChildrenRecursive<T>(currentChild))
            {
                if (subChild != null)
                    yield return casted;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andreas Müller, But I just want to change on xaml file.

Comment: this isn't about wanting something. it's about how the platform allows it to be designed. what you want is impossible using just xaml

Comment: stackpanel is under treeview. So I can change background item of treeview then stackpanel has changed (stackpanel is an item). But **AAA** is item background, A**AA** is stackpanel background (I want this view).

Comment: **A** has color. A has not color

Comment: @GSP did you use the ActiveColor Property too?

Comment: Sorry, I has researched xaml yesterday. So how can i do with ActiveColor Property ?

Comment: @GSP Well that explains it :) You just exchange your textblock with a RadioTextblock and then you set the property in Xaml as usual with the color you want to be used upon a click

Comment: **RadioTextblock**: `The type RadioTextblock was not found`

Comment: look up "referencing custom controls". you'll have to reference a namespace to a namespace shortcut like it's usually in windows, controls etc. later on you use that shortcut to do it like <customNamespace:RadioTextbox ActiveColor="Red">yourtext</customNamespace:RadioTextbox> and that's it

Answer (score 0):

Change your `XAML` structure as follow's

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:your_assembly_Name"
.....  
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:BackgroundConverter x:Key="backgroundConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="TextBlockMouseDownEvent" />
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource backgroundConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Name" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                        <Binding Path="SelectedTextBlockName"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock x:Name="text1" Text="Header"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="text2" Text="Header"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="text3" Text="Header"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="text4" Text="Header"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Use following `IMultiValueConverter` and Add `TextBlockMouseDownEvent` Event Handler as well as One `DependencyProperty` in your code behind.

```
////DependencyProperty
public string SelectedTextBlockName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedTextBlockNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedTextBlockNameProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedTextBlock.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTextBlockNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedTextBlockName", typeof(string), typeof(Class_Name), new PropertyMetadata(null));

.......

private void TextBlockMouseDownEvent(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock txtBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    if (txtBlock != null)
    {
        SelectedTextBlockName = txtBlock.Name;
    }
}

.......

public class BackgroundConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Values[0] = Name of TextBlock
    /// values[1] = SelectedTextBlockName
    /// If matches then it is selected
    /// </summary>
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] != null && values[1] != null && values[0].ToString() == values[1].ToString())
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If you want to set default SelectedTextBlock then just set the TextBlock name which you want as a default to be selected.
like this :

```
SelectedTextBlockName = "text1";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I also want to change in xaml file. And I found the answer for me: This is post of `**Heena Patil**`